# Optimizing code for speed

Tags: java, mysql, optimization

I've written what seems to be a prohibitively slow program where it is taking many minutes rather than seconds to read and write data from a database. It appears to be slowing down a great deal in my *runComparisons* method below although im unsure what steps I should take to correct this.

**[full program](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/191f7fdbc009d029d41a9e07cec955a2)**

```
 public static void runComparisons(String industryTitle, List<String> tickerName, TradingInterval tradingInterval) throws SQLException {

        // Get primary performance values ticker return
        for (String ticker : tickerName) {
            String startDate = tradingInterval.beginDate;
            //System.out.println("start date " + startDate);
            String endDate = tradingInterval.endDate;
            //System.out.println("end date " + endDate);
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement
                    ("select P.TransDate, P.openPrice, P.closePrice" +
                            " from PriceVolume P" +
                            " where Ticker = ? and TransDate>= ? and TransDate <= ?" +
                            "order by TransDate DESC");

            statement.setString(1, ticker);
            statement.setString(2, startDate);
            statement.setString(3, endDate);
            ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

            String date;
            double nextOpenPrice = 0.0;
            double currentClosePrice;
            //int numberDays = 1;
            //int splitCounter = 0;
            double divideAmount = 1;
            String tickerSymbol = "";

            // create list to contain dates for use in investment strategy
            ArrayList<holdSplitVals> ascendingList = new ArrayList<>();


            // process result set
            while (result.next()) {
                //tickerSymbol = result.getString("Ticker");
                // reset split amount for next iteration
                date = result.getString("TransDate");
                double openPrice = result.getDouble("OpenPrice");
                double closePrice = result.getDouble("ClosePrice");


                currentClosePrice = closePrice;
                // get closing/opening ratio

                double splitAmount = getRatios(date, nextOpenPrice, currentClosePrice);


                if (splitAmount > 0) {
                    divideAmount = divideAmount * splitAmount;
                    //splitCounter++;
                }

                // hold data in helper class
                holdSplitVals data = new holdSplitVals();
                data.date = date;
                data.openPrice = openPrice / divideAmount;
                data.closePrice = closePrice / divideAmount;

                ascendingList.add(0, data);

                nextOpenPrice = openPrice;

                if (ascendingList.size() >= 1) {

                    outputTable(closePrice, openPrice, industryTitle, tickerSymbol, startDate, endDate);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void outputTable(double closePrice, double openPrice, String industryTitle, String tickerSymbol, String startDate, String endDate) throws SQLException {
        double tickerNumber = (closePrice / openPrice) - 1;
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.####");
        df.setRoundingMode(RoundingMode.CEILING);
        String tickerNum = df.format(tickerNumber);

        PreparedStatement writeStatement = writerconn.prepareStatement(
                "insert into Performance(Industry, Ticker, StartDate, EndDate, TickerReturn)"
                        + "values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        writeStatement.setString(1, industryTitle);
        writeStatement.setString(2, tickerSymbol);
        writeStatement.setString(3, startDate);
        writeStatement.setString(4, endDate);
        writeStatement.setString(5, tickerNum);

        writeStatement.executeUpdate();
    }

    private static double getRatios(String date, double nextOpenPrice, double currentClosePrice) {
        double coRatio = currentClosePrice / nextOpenPrice;
        // calculate splits
        // for 2:1 split
        if (Math.abs(coRatio - 2.0) < 0.20) {
            //splitCounter++;
            //splitDate = ("2:1 split on " + date);
            //System.out.println("2:1 split on " + date + " " + currentClosePrice + "--> " + nextOpenPrice);
            return 2.0;
            // for 3:1 split
        } else if (Math.abs(coRatio - 3.0) < 0.20) {
            //splitCounter++;
            //splitDate = ("3:1 split on "+ date);
            //System.out.println("3:1 split on " + date + " " + currentClosePrice + "--> " + nextOpenPrice);
            return 3.0;
            // for 3:2 split
        } else if (Math.abs(coRatio - 1.5) < 0.15) {
            //splitCounter++;
            //splitDate = ("3:2 split on " + date);
            //System.out.println("3:2 split on " + date + " " + currentClosePrice + "--> " + nextOpenPrice);
            return 1.5;
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The point of a `PreparedStatement` is that it is prepared once and used many times. Furthermore you should be using the JDBC Batch API instead of individual inserts.

Comment: One thing that may improve your code is to just create the prepared statements once and use `clearParameters()` before each call

Comment: If you have many tickers, one optimization might be to execute the statement only once instead per ticker, i.e. change it to `... where Ticker in (?) ...` and add the ticker to the resultset.

Comment: I haven’t got much experience with profilers, but they say they are great for finding where the time is used in a program. It may be worth considering.

Comment: @Thomas for the for the first run comparison statement yeah to avoid recreating the statement each time? Would you be able to write out what you mean? Im not sure what the formatting will look like.

Comment: It's not only about creating the statement only once - you could do that without changing the query. However, it's about how oft you execute the query. Executing one query instead of multiple ones would probably reduce overhead introduced by communication, query parsing/preparation etc. So what I mean is a query like `select p.ticker, ... from PriceVolumne p where ticker in (?) and ...` and collect the data into some structure before using batches to write the results back (note that I adapted the naming to a more Java-code-conventions like style).